# POS Printer (Impresora fiscal)

Tags: c#, impresora

Estoy ejecutando el código de pruebas que proporciona Epson al instalar los drivers.
El tema es que me da un error (*ILLEGAL*) al realizar el *claim(1000)*.

```
 // Console.WriteLine("Initializing PosExplorer ");
PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();

// Console.WriteLine("Taking FiscalPrinter device ");
DeviceInfo fp = posExplorer.GetDevice("FiscalPrinter", "FiscalPrinter1");

// Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of FiscalPrinter device ");
PosCommon posCommonFP = (PosCommon)posExplorer.CreateInstance(fp);
posCommonFP.StatusUpdateEvent += new StatusUpdateEventHandler(co_OnStatusUpdateEvent);

// Console.WriteLine("Initializing FiscalPrinter ");
FiscalPrinter fiscalprinter = (FiscalPrinter) posCommonFP;

Console.WriteLine("Performing Open() method ");
fiscalprinter.Open();

Console.WriteLine("Performing Claim() method ");
fiscalprinter.Claim(1000); // Exception
```

Mensaje error:
**ErrorCode: Illegal

ErrorCodeExtended: 10002

Message: Stub message. LockPort Error. IORet = 4**

¿Alguien sabe como funciona o qué me falla?

[Pregunta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430995/cant-claim-the-posprinter)

Comment: En windows 10 no he podido hacer funcionar POS for .net, ademas, ya no tiene soporte oficial.

Answer (score 0):

La impresora fiscal del modelo FP-81 II funciona con el puerto 9100 que es el que se debe de modificar en la ventana de configuración del NPort.

[image: Configuración del NPort]